# Azure Service Fabric Cluster returns nothing for code-versions and config-versions

Tags: azure-service-fabric

In short: both the "`sfctl cluster code-versions`" and "`sfctl cluster config-versions`" return empty arrays. Is this a symptom of a problem with the cluster?

Background: I am attempting to follow the [Create a Linux container app tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-tutorial-create-container-images), for learning about Service Fabric; but I have run into a problem when the application upload fails with a timeout.
On investigating this, I found that the other `sfctl cluster` commands (e.g. `sfctl cluster health`) all worked and returned useful data - except `code-versions` and `config-versions`, which both return an empty array:

```
$ sfctl cluster code-versions
[]

$ sfctl cluster config-versions
[]
```

I'm not sure if that's unhealthy, or what kind of data they might be returning.

---

Other notes:

1. The cluster is secured with a self-signed certificate; this is installed locally and works correctly, but both the above commands also log a warning:
   `~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py:847: InsecureRequestWarning: Unverified HTTPS request is being made. Adding certificate verification is strongly advised. See: https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced-usage.html#ssl-warnings InsecureRequestWarning)`
   However, the same warning is logged for the other commands (e.g. `sysctl cluster health`) and doesn't stop them from working.
2. The cluster is at version 6.4.634.1, on Linux
3. Service Fabric Explorer shows everything as Healthy: Cluster Health State, System Application Health State, and the 3 nodes.
4. The Azure portal shows the cluster status as "Baseline upgrade"
5. Explorer shows the cluster as having Code Version "0.0.0.0"

Comment: The `baseline upgrade` status usually takes a while. After that you should have a working cluster. Can you try again and see what happens?

Comment: I think the root of my problem is that the baseline upgrade isn't finishing. I've left it overnight, and it hasn't got any further.

Comment: I agree, maybe create a support call?